# Change a button text that includes image using javascript - using escape single quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, button

I have a button with the following HTML code that works fine when it first runs:

```
<button type='button' class='btn-success chbtn' id ='basketbutton'>Click to see basket <img class='btnbasket' src='images/cart.png' alt='Cart'/> ".$basketnumber." items</button>
```

The $basketnumber comes from a XMLHttpRequest request with the current basket total from the database.

If gives me a the button I want with a message 'click to see basket' with an image of a shopping cart and 'X item'.

After adding an item to the shopping cart, updating databases etc I am updating the webpage elements to include the new purchase.

The webpage is constructed using php and inserts a js function in script tags in the header to update the elements and has the line (in php) :

```
document.getElementById('basketbutton').innerHTML=  'Click to see basket <img class='btnbasket' src='images/White shopping cart.png' alt='Cart'/>   ' +obj.baskettotal+ ' items';
```

the obj.baskettotal comes from a XMLHttpRequest request with the current basket total from the database

This does not work. The console tells me i have 'Uncaught ReferenceError: [js function] is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick'

When I remove the image reference :

```
document.getElementById('basketbutton').innerHTML=  'Click to see basket ' +obj.baskettotal+ ' items';
```

everything works great.

I think it's the way I am using the single quotes and the img reference that also contains them  that is messing things up. The double quotes that define the text are not there and I somehow need to get them defined in php so I can build up the script properly.

I have tried using the  `&#34;` HTML code in the php code but this does nothing and does not come through as double quotes (it remains as `&#34;` on the HTML page in the jS function) and the error still occurs.

I have tried using `.innertext` and `.textcontent` to no avail

I was hoping someone could help me in the right direction

Comment: you need to escape the quote marks within the string e.g. `\' ` or use double-quotes instead. JS thinks the innerHTML string value ends at `class='`, and then of course everything after that is then meaningless to it, which results in a syntax error.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle please, to assist you? https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting in your IDE / in the snippet output in your question.  You should be able to see that the `'` is terminating your string rather than inserting a `'`.

Comment: @ADyson I think you are right the quote marks. I am using php to build the page up and need to get my head around the escape quote and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: @jammi  I have tinkered with JSfiddle but not an expert. The main code I have that the webpage is based on is php that writes it into HTML. The issue I think is in the way I am writing the php code and the way its passed over to HTML. If I wrote it properly in HTML/Javascript with the double quotes in the right place it works.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the right single quotes works for me as suggested by @ADyson :)

```
document.getElementById('basketbutton').innerHTML=  'Click to see basket <img class=\'btnbasket\' src=\'images/White shopping cart.png\' alt=\'Cart\'/> ' +obj.baskettotal+ ' items';
```

Many thanks for the pointer. I first made the mistake of escaping the quotes round the XMLHttpRequest request response (obj.baskettotal) and that should up as text instead of the value!